# Wireless router DSL connection problem help

Tags: wireless-router, dsl

I recently bought a wireless DSL router to replace my *wired* one. After quick setup however, the router does not connect to the Internet. Wireless connection between laptop and router exists and Internet can be connected through laptop(manually) by using router as WAN miniport(PPPoE).

What I want to do is connect the wireless router to Internet so that when laptop connects to router, I can start using the Internet. How do I do this? Please help.

Comment: *"…by using router as WAN miniport(PPPoE)."* Sounds to me like this is what you want. What wireless router do you have and what DSL modem do you have (or is it a combined thing)?

Comment: Its a combined thing- from a chinese company called Tenda.